# How do Disable add to cart button using javascript in woocommerce Single Product Page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to disable the 'add to cart' button using jQuery's ajax success function.

I'm trying to get the class name because the button has no ID.

I have tried this code but it does not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#checked').click(function() {  
    var form_data = new FormData();           
    var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
    form_data.append('action', 'acao_checar');

    $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl, 
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text', 
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,

      success: function(data){
        document.getElementsByClassName('single_add_to_cart_button').disabled = true;
      },

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If you create an alert or a console.log statement in your success function, does that run as expected?

Comment: @markmoxx, yes alert command work normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, I have used this code:

```
$('.single_add_to_cart_button').prop("disabled", true);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` always returns an array, so you probably want to use `document.getElementsByClassName('single_add_to_cart_button')[0].disabled = true;`

Comment: @FOR If you console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('single_add_to_cart_button')), what do you get?

Comment: its return HTMLCollection []
length: 0